# Permission Denied to UNLINK from Crontab

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I am using Crontab through cPanel to delete files and directories uploaded by clients using a PHP script. This has the images within the directory set as 0644 owner 99 group 99.

When the following scheduled crontab is executed I get permission denied errors.

php -q -f /xxx/xxx/xxx/deletefiles.php

```
function RemoveDirectory($dirname) {
    if (!file_exists($dirname)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (is_file($dirname) || is_link($dirname)) {
        return unlink($dirname);
    }
    $dir = dir($dirname);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        RemoveDirectory($dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $entry);
    }
    $dir->close();
    return rmdir($dirname);
}
if (is_dir('/xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx')) {
    RemoveDirectory('/xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx');
}
```

If I run this same script myself through PHP it works just fine. How do I give crontab permission to run the same scripting? Do I have to place this file within the root directory? Which I prefer not to.

How I explain this correctly. Any help appropriated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the permissions by using [chmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) before you delete it. Something like:

```
if (is_file($dirname) || is_link($dirname)) {
    chmod($dirname, 0777);
    return unlink($dirname);
}


if (is_dir('/xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx')) {
    chmod("/xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx", 0777);
    RemoveDirectory('/xxx/xxx/public_html/xxx/xxx');
}
```

Comment: That didn't do it. Should that be done on each file (image) as well?

Comment: Probably. I don't think the server would let you delete the folder without being able to delete the files.

Comment: I get a chmod(): Operation not permitted

Comment: I wish I could help more, but I just tried your script on my server using cron. I got the same error initially about permission denied. Then I set the chmod in the first place that I mentioned and it worked for me. The only thing I can think of is that somehow you're not running the script as the owner (root user) or that you're trying to run the script from another server. Oh, and I didn't use the `-q -f` like you did. I'm not really up on cron, so I'm not sure what that's for :)

Comment: Then there has to be something up with the server. Thanks for you help though. I will have to do some more research myself.